# Meaning of "straight" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Could you help me get a job? I don't know, something **straight**.
> A place to clock in and out of if I wanted.

Any synonyms for "straight" in this context? And how to paraphrase this sentence: "A place to clock in and out of"?

The speaker is a former prisoner.

Comment: Do you know what _clocking in_ means? You haven't told us the context of the question, but I'm guessing that the speaker wants a simple job that doesn't require too much thought.

Comment: "Somewhere you can clock in and out of" perhaps means "with flexible working hours."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Straight** here means legitimate and normal.  This phrase is usually used to contrast a job with a job that is not a regular, 9 to 5 professional job with a regular paycheck.  For example,

> [Some, because of a history of drug addiction or criminal felonies, are unable to obtain a straight job.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qv_zAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22straight%20job%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrpnv1Yz5AhUzF1kFHTK7Bjo4ChDoAXoECAkQAg)

> [...you'll need $50,000 in savings to start your life as a full-time professional poker player. I suggest to anyone considering this that you keep your straight job...](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9vNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT212&dq=%22straight%20job%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrpnv1Yz5AhUzF1kFHTK7Bjo4ChDoAXoECAcQAg)

At many jobs, when you arrive, you **clock in** (you record the time that you arrive), and when you leave, you **clock out** (record the time that you leave), so that you can be paid for the hours that you work.

The implication is that speaker is asking for help getting a job that is *not* illegal, or "off the books", or has irregular hours.